# I am using botium box for conversation flow testing, how to configure DTMF input in that

Tags: dtmf

While using botium box for voice flow testing, how to configure DTMF inputs in the test cases? I tried using buttons, but it won't work.

How to add DTMF inputs in the test cases? I am using dialogflow CX connector for configuration. So is there any workaround which can help adding DTMF?